# SharePoint 2007 Survey Redirection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, survey

Afternoon all,

Fairly simple one this one but one that seems to be beyond me today.  SharePoint 2007 survey that I'd like to redirect once the user hits finish.  I have a custom Thankyou.aspx page for this.

As the SharePoint 2007 survey forms don't appear to allow me to add web parts or edit the pages, I've embedded a SharePoint form control into a Web Part Page to give me more options.

JQuery is an option as it's installed in my local environment and I only have access to SharePoint Designer 2007 and client side dev.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is based on the redirection from the empty page inserted into the end of a Survey form.

Solution:

- Add `Page Separator` at the end of Survey list (see pic. below)
  in order to insert an additional empty page [image]
- Embed the following JavaScript code into Survey edit form

Snippet: redirects from the last Survey page

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


(function(){
   var fieldName = getParameterByName('FirstField');
   if(fieldName == "ID"){
          window.location.href = "/pages/thankyou.aspx";
   }    

})();
```

Comment: This'll need to be embedded via SPD I think.  I'll put it in the PlaceHolder main and will test.  Thanks for the snippet.